# get ip of emr master node from yarn cli

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, sed, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

In order to get a list of the ip addresses of emr slave nodes, one must run the following code:

```
yarn node -list 2>/dev/null \
| sed -n "s/^\(ip[^:]*\):.*/\1/p"
```

`yarn node -list` happens to print off the ip of the master node to `stderr`:

> 19/04/02 18:59:26 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-10-1-0-238.ec2.internal/10.1.0.238:8032

**How would I modify the above code to get the private ip of the emr master node instead?**

Comment: if the ip address is printed to stderr then you should replace `2>/dev/null` with `2>&1` in your command

Comment: that's a start, but how would i modify the `sed` pattern matching to get the master IP?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running on Amazon Elastic Map Reduce, this will read the master IP address from the jobflow JSON object and parse it out with `jq`:

```
jq .masterPrivateDnsName /emr/instance-controller/lib/info/job-flow.json
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
yarn node -list |& sed 's/.*ip-\([^.]*\).*/\1/g'
```

where `|&` is a shorthand for `2>&1`. This returns:

```
10-1-0-238
```

Comment: lol so... that didn't work... but it turns out you can just type `hostname -f`.  thanks though!